# Query work items directy on sql database incase wiql

Tags: tfs, wiql

Because fetch work items from wiql that is very low. I would like to fetch them from database directly but I don't know which table should I get them?

Comment: Is the TFS database directly exposed to you?

Answer (score 1):

there are 9 views that are intended for creating reports in TFS 2012:

```
CurrentWorkItemView
WorkItemHistoryView
BuildChangesetView
BuildCoverageView
BuildDetailsView
BuildProjectView
CodeChurnView
RunCoverageView
TestResultView
```

Please find more info at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2010/05/09/tfs2010-how-to-query-work-items-using-sql-on-the-relational-warehouse.aspx